# Stop using mobile specific page for Android browsers

Tags: support, mobile-web

For me, the front page is near useless if it's not filtered by my tags.  The mobile version is way too simple and restricted, it doesn't use my tags by default, nor does it even display them.  Short of beefing up the mobile page, I'd really prefer the full version sent to my reasonably capable Android phone.

Comment: This is usually an option on your phone's web browser.  Look into it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So in your reasonably capable Android phone browser, scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page, find the link that reads, "full site", and click it.

[image: A picture of that full site link]

Voilà! No dumbed-down mobile site. And if you decide to go back, you'll find a link labelled "mobile" where the "full site" one sat previously.

Comment: Wow.  I feel a little guilty I never found that.